# NativeBase: override style on single element

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a `Text` component that I need to modify for one screen only (not restyling the entire theme). I tried to follow the [NativeBase 2.0 documentation](http://nativebase.io/docs/v2.0.0/customize#themingNativeBaseApp) but found it very confusing. Is there a simple way to just change the style of that one element without having to copy the entire theme into project?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Grid, Col, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class JobListDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem>
        <Grid>
          <Col>
            <Text style={styles.redText}>Some Text</Text>
            <Text>Another text</Text>
          </Col>
        </Grid>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  redText: {
    color: 'red'
  },
});
```

Comment: Using the **style** prop should be enough. If you look at their source code, they're already using any prop you pass to that component:  [Native Base Text](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Text.js)

Comment: That's what I thought but then the styling was just ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeBase Text overrides the `style`'s [StyleSheetPropType](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetPropType.js) to become [PropTypes.object](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Text.js#L18).

Remove the `StyleSheet.create` to apply the new style:

```
const styles = {
  redText: {
    color: 'red'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The styles get applied, however there is a warning that keeps getting thrown.

```
<Text style={labelStyle}>
    {title}
</Text>
const styles = {
    pending: {
        color: '#000'
    },
    complete: {
        textDecorationLine: 'line-through',
        color: '#d8d8d8'
    }
};
```

This will throw 
[image]
There is an open high priority issue filed here https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/610